# wrapRootElement is not a function when building gatsby on cloud

Tags: gatsby

Locally works fine, I am able to build and serve my project without any issues. However if I push my code to Gatsby cloud, I get:

```
TypeError: plugin.wrapRootElement is not a function
    at wrappers (/usr/src/app/www/.cache/caches/gatsby-plugin-mdx/webpack/webpack:/<project-name-here>/node_modules/gatsby-plugin-mdx/utils/wrap-root-render-html-entry.js:12:33)
```

It appeared out of nowhere, I have no changes in code, I trigger empty build manually via gatsby cloud. Any ideas why this became an issue suddenly?

Comment: Are you using `wrapRootElement`? If so, can you share the corresponding snippet?

Comment: @FerranBuireu, no Im not.

Comment: I'm also experiencing this issue. Cannot reproduce locally (would be nice to know the build context of gatsby cloud to try and do so).

Comment: @Ponelat, I managed to solve this issue by deleting all the changes that have been made to yarn.lock file. Not sure what happened there, but I took last working version's yarn.lock, put into my branch, and it went through.